# variable interpolation in bash alias

Tags: bash

I have alias: 
alias asd='myvar=$1 echo \"Hey $myvar Bye\"'

But when I run the command asd 44 I get the output "Hey Bye" 44. Can someone explain why the echo is run last and how I can get the desired result of "Hey 44 Bye"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Aliases don't do positional expansion; use a function instead.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080)