# To set printf in alias

Tags: linux, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [variable interpolation in bash alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421436/variable-interpolation-in-bash-alias)

This command is used to set the title of my console in bash shell

```
    printf "\033]0;  my_console_title \007";
```

But I want use this command with alias and should accept the console title from user
(having trouble with setting printf to alias variable).

Something similar to :

```
alias fx="find . -type f | xargs grep -il $1"
```

Usage: `fx "search_text"`

Comment: Aliases don't take arguments well.  Make it into a tiny shell script; they do handle arguments.  Put in your private (`$HOME/bin`) directory.  Bonus: your shell will be slightly faster since it has fewer aliases to process; you only incur the overhead when you use it (and the overhead won't be noticeable anyway).  Or use a function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : But I have been using this alias   **alias fx="find . -type f | xargs grep -il $1"**. Its accepting arguments and working fine

Comment: Your `fx` alias works because the arguments go at the end, not in the middle. If your arguments were supposed to modify the `find` command rather than the `grep` command, I believe you'd have problems. I believe you'd see the same results as now if you omitted the `$1` completely from your `fx` alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
alias title='printf "\033];0%s\007"'
```

BTW, on URXVT your line does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ alias ttt='printf "\033]0; %s \007" "$1"'
```

Can't test it since it doesn't work on my machine but at least it gives no errors.

Edit: Ups. Fixed an error.

Comment: not working :(
It removes the existing title

Comment: try it again pls. i made a typo before